# Unzip password protected file in universal windows application

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal, unzip

am trying to decompress password protected file in universal windows application,using c#

can any one give suggestion

native System.IO.Compression does not  work with encrypted zip

Dontnetzip have issues with windows 10 versions

Comment: I don't see any C#, and trust me, it's not that I don't _speak_ C#.

Comment: most of libs dont work in uwp that why no code

Comment: Could try chillkat. https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_uwp.asp and example https://www.example-code.com/csharp_winrt/zip_passwordProtect1.asp

Comment: is it free or paid?

Answer (score 0):

as suggest by tycobb using Chilkat.Zip

```
 Chilkat.Zip zip = new Zip();
        bool success = zip.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");

        zip.DecryptPassword = "psss";
        bool opensucess = await zip.OpenZipAsync(storageFolder.Path + "\\sample.zip");
        int unzipsucess = await zip.UnzipAsync(storageFolder.Path);
```